# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, module, package

I keep having this issue with the code I had written, I cant figure out why.

My project structure:

```
├──code
|  ├── Bot_Tracker
|  |   ├── __init__.py
|  |   ├── matchhistory.py
|  |   ├── discordUI.py
|  ├── Tests
|  |   ├── __init__.py
|  |   └── test_matchhistory.py
```

My import statements in `test_matchhistory.py`:

```
from Bot_Tracker.matchhistory import compMatchHistory
```

I don't understand why I keep getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a simple problem related to how Python works out where packages are stored. If the package is not in the python path, then python won't be able to access it on the import.

To solve this I needed to add the package directory and the parent to the package directory to the system path.

The code I used:

```
from os import path
import sys

if __package__:
    parent_dir = path.dirname(__file__)
    root_dir = path.dirname(parent_dir)
    if parent_dir not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(parent_dir)
    if root_dir not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(root_dir)
```

This code basically finds the directory where the file is stored then and the parent of that directory, after which it checks if the paths to this directories exist in `sys.path`.